# Get user details in Active Directory using pre-Windows 2000 domain name

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm not familiar with LDAP yet I'm integrating my app users with Active Directory. I want to accomplish two things:

1. Validate username and password.
2. Get user details.

Correct or not, the first part seemingly works:

```
$ldap = ldap_connect('ldap:foo.example.local ldap:bar.example.local');
if(!$ldap){
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$is_valid_user = ldap_bind($ldap, 'john.doe@example.local', 'passw0rd');
$is_valid_user = ldap_bind($ldap, 'example\\john.doe', 'passw0rd');
```

Unfortunately, the second part only retrieves results if I use the Windows 2000 domain name format, `example.local`:

```
$results = ldap_search($ldap, 'DC=example,DC=local', '(sAMAccountName=john.doe)');
if(!$results){
    return new RuntimeException();
}
ldap_sort($ldap, $results, 'sn');
$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results);
ldap_close($ldap);
```

With pre-Windows 2000 domain names (i.e., using just `'DC=example'` as second argument for `ldap_search`) the `ldap_get_entries()` function returns:

```
array (
    'count' => 0,
)
```

I understand we are in 2019 but I'd like to keep my class as generic as possible.

Is there a simple change I can make to keep my code compatible with both formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you're looking at the "Account" tab of a user in Active Directory Users and Computers, the "User logon name" corresponds to the [`userPrincipalName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-userprincipalname) attribute. The "User logon name (pre-Windows 2000)" is a combination of the NetBIOS domain name (the "short" domain name) and the [`sAMAccountName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-samaccountname) attribute of the user.

Either one of those can be used to login. As shown in your code, you only need one of these lines, since they both do the same thing.

```php
$is_valid_user = ldap_bind($ldap, 'john.doe@example.local', 'passw0rd');
$is_valid_user = ldap_bind($ldap, 'example\\john.doe', 'passw0rd');
```

In the second one, you can actually remove `example\` as long as the user `john.doe` is on the same domain that you are connecting to. You only need to provide the domain name if the user credentials are from a different domain (which is possible if you have trusts between domains).

You must include the `@example.local` when specifying the `userPrincipalName`, since that is actually all part of the attribute and the part after `@` does not necessarily need to match the domain name.

This:

```php
$results = ldap_search($ldap, 'DC=example,DC=local', '(sAMAccountName=john.doe)');
```

Only works if you "use the Windows 2000 domain name format" because that's all you're searching for. If you want to match either format, you will need to match against the `userPrincipalName` too. You can do that by using the OR operator `|`:

```php
$results = ldap_search($ldap, 'DC=example,DC=local', '(|(sAMAccountName=john.doe)(userPrincipalName=john.doe))');
```

Then your user can give you either format and you should be able to find the account.

> With pre-Windows 2000 domain names (i.e., using just `'DC=example'` as second argument for `ldap_search`)

That will never work because the second argument in `ldap_search` is the "base DN". This is the `distinguishedName` of the container you want to search. That will usually be the top level of the domain. The `distinguishedName` of the top level of the domain will be `DC=example,DC=local'. But you could also put the DN of an OU there if you only want to look in that OU, like:`OU=Users,DC=example,DC=local'

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking dumb questions but this is an LDAP crash course for me. Do you mean that I absolutely need to know the full Windows 2000 domain name (`example.local`) to search for a user because NetBIOS name (`example`) does not contain enough information to identify the base DN?

Comment: Most applications that support LDAP ask for the base DN, since that allows you to limit the scope to an OU, which you might want. However, you can find the base DN of the domain by querying the `defaultNamingContext` attribute of the [RootDSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/rootdse). There is an example of how to do that in PHP [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ldap.controls.php). That example reads the `supportedcontrol` attribute, so just replace that with `defaultNamingContext`.

Comment: I think that there is an error in `(|(sAMAccountName=john.doe)(userPrincipalName=john.doe))` . At least for my Windows Domain Controller, the field `userPrincipalName` has the value `john.doe@example.com` , not `john.doe`.

Comment: @DanielMarschall You're right in that specific case. But this is talking about using the user's input and matching against either `sAMAccountName` or `userPrincipalName`. So if the user gave you `john.doe` as their username, then yes, the search query would be exactly like that and it would match to the `sAMAccountName`. But if the user provided `john.doe@example.com`, then the query would be `(|(sAMAccountName=john.doe@example.com)(userPrincipalName=john.doe@example.com))` and it would end up matching the `userPrincipalName`.

Comment: So in real world use, `john.doe` would not be hard coded, but would be whatever the user provided.

Answer (score 0):

I've composed a proof of concept with [Gabriel Luci's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59052139/13508) (great info is his, errors are mine):

```
<?php

$ldap = ldap_connect('ldap:foo.example.local ldap:bar.example.local');
if(!$ldap){
    throw new RuntimeException();
}
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
if(!ldap_bind($ldap, 'example\\lookup.user', 'passw0rd')){
    throw new RuntimeException();
}

$result = ldap_read($ldap, '', '(objectClass=*)', ['defaultNamingContext']);
$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
if(isset($info[0]['defaultnamingcontext'][0])){
    $base_dn = $info[0]['defaultnamingcontext'][0]; // E.g. 'DC=example,DC=local'
}else{
    throw new RuntimeException();
}

$results = ldap_search($ldap, $base_dn, '(|(sAMAccountName=john.doe)(userPrincipalName=john.doe))');
if(!$results){
    return new RuntimeException();
}
$info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results);
var_dump($info);
ldap_close($ldap);
```

Comment: I think that there is an error in `(|(sAMAccountName=john.doe)(userPrincipalName=john.doe))` . At least for my Windows Domain Controller, the field `userPrincipalName` has the value `john.doe@example.com` , not `john.doe`.

Comment: @DanielMarschall The idea is that there's a default (or often just one) domain to be used when the user doesn't provide a fully-qualified username. But this is just a quick proof of concept and I didn't really have a multi-domain setup to test.